# git log: exclude commits that only modify certain subfolder?

Tags: git, gettext, git-log

When writing the release notes for a new version of a project, sometimes it is interesting to distinguish which contributors are developers and which are just translators.

For this, in the case of *gettext*-based projects, one could simply use `git log` but just taking in account all the subfolders of a project which are **not** named `po`.

I've seen that `git log` accepts a *path* argument, but how to achieve the opposite? Supply a path to be **discarded**, instead of taken in account? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can exclude the folders named `po` and display all collaborators of other folders as follows.

```
git log -- . '!po/*' --no-merges "$@" | grep ^Author: | sed 's/ <.*//; s/^Author: //' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Comment: this gives the following error: `bash: !po/*: event not found`

Comment: The command should start with `git log -- . '!po/*'` I changed double quotes to single quotes and updated my answer

Comment: Ok, now it doesn't give an error, but the result is incorrect. For example, I've run this in banshee repo (https://github.com/GNOME/banshee) and it has displayed Antón Méixome author, which has only contributed a translation: https://github.com/GNOME/banshee/commit/4e72563350b840686108be75fcf1a904c2be52c0

Comment: @knocte Interesting. I cloned the repository and ran the same command on master branch. You can check the result from http://pastebin.com/fUBkB01G I couldn't see Antón Méixome in the list.

Comment: your results are also wrong: there are only 49 contributions from me listed, but I already have more than 400 commits (my surname is Aragoneses)